# Посмотреть грязное чтение на сервере

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

> Объясните, пожалуйста, как на сервере увидеть результат изменений в таблице в процессе  транзакции.
> Дело в том, что таблица заблокирована, прописал как посоветовали здесь https://www.sql.ru/forum/1083177/tranzakciya-blokiruet-vsu-tablicu
> https://infostart.ru/public/708848/
> перевести базу в read committed snapshot прописал в запросе ALTER DATABASE ShopDB SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF но ничего не изменилось
> То есть в консоль могу вывести грязные данные, но нельзя открыть таблице в Managament Studio

Программа состоит из двух транзакций. первая добавляет с учетом ввода пользователя запись на сервере. Вторая считывает данные перед их откатом первой транзакцией.

```
//Первая транзакция
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Configuration;

namespace HW2._2pt1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /*
        static void f1()
        {

        }
        */
        static void f2(int buf2)
        {
            string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN; Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

           // string comStr = "Delete from Products where ProdID=@buf2";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p2", connection)
            { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProdID", buf2);

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN; Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p1", connection)
            { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };

            Console.WriteLine("Введите цену: ");
            var price = Console.ReadLine();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);



            Console.WriteLine("Step1 Press any key to execute command...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            connection.Open();

            cmd.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            var buf = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Step 3 Press any key to rollback Transaction");
            Console.ReadKey();

            //f2(buf);

            cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
            connection.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Transaction Rollback");
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Вторая транзакция
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace HW2._2pt2
{
    static class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN; Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

            string comStr = "Select * from Products";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comStr, connection);

            Console.WriteLine("Step 2 Press any key to see Products: ");
            Console.ReadKey();

            connection.Open();
            cmd.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
            SqlDataReader readez = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (readez.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < readez.FieldCount; i++) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", readez.GetName(i), readez[i]);
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Процедуры
Alter proc p1 
@price int
as
begin
set IDENTITY_INSERT Products ON;
Insert Products(ProdID, [Description], UnitPrice, [Weight])Values
(14, 'Шлем', @price, 500)
return @@identity;
end
go


create proc p2
@buf int
as
begin
Delete from Products where ProdID = @buf
end
go

ALTER DATABASE ShopDB SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
```

При этом если во второй транзакции прописать ReadCommitted вместо ReadUncommitted, то считывания не произойдет
При этом, если на сервере вместо ALTER DATABASE ShopDB SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF указать ALTER DATABASE ShopDB SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON, то вторая транзакция даже при ReadCommitted считает данные из таблицы, но в них не будет грязных данных. Может это и имелось ввиду?

[image: Попытка увидеть таблицу с грязными данными]

[image]

[image: когда на сервере ON/OFF, во второй транзакции OFF]

[image: когда на сервере ON и во второй транзакции ON]